# what is the life time of static variable in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net

I have created an console application which i am scheduling in Task Scheduler as job. I have one class level Static variable in my application, below is the sample code. When my job runs for the first time, no issue. When i rerun the job immediately, I get "Object reference" error as I am setting it to NULL in finally block and doing "sb.clear()" in try block - static variable will be initialized only once.

```
Class Temp
{
   public static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   try
   {
       sb.clear();
       ... some code
   }
   catch
   {}
   finally
   {
      sb = null
   }
}
```

My Task Scheduler job will run on every 24 hours. Since i set the variable to NULL, will this be Garbage collected after some time of first run? This way i wont run into "Object Reference" error when my job runs for second time after 24 hours (considering static variable will be created again).

I want to know what is the life time of static variable if i set this to NULL and if not i set this to NULL. Please clarify.

Comment: If this object only exists to be used in the context of a particular method run once every so often then *it shouldn't be stored in a static variable*.  It should be scoped to the specific operation that needs it.  This prevents you from needing to know when you can and can't use a given variable, and creating bugs, like the one you apparently have, that involve using a variable when it isn't supposed to be.  If you create it when you need it, and have that variable leave scope when the operation is done *you can't have bugs like that*.  The GC is not your priority, working code is.

Answer (score 0):

The life time of a static varible is as long as your application is running. 
See more details here:

[Scope and persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986051/c-sharp-static-variables-scope-and-persistence)
[Lifetime of data in variable static](https://forums.asp.net/t/1974003.aspx?Lifetime%20of%20data%20in%20static%20variable%20c%20)

I hope to this information be usefull

Comment: If i assign NULL to the variable, wont it be ready for garbage collection during GC cycle. Please advise.

Comment: Variables are not subjects for the GC process - objects are. If you assign a NULL to the variable, then you simply remove a reference to an object which exists somewhere in the heap. That object will be collected by the GC only if it's not referenced anywhere else in the program.

Answer (score -2):

sb.clear(); //this cannot be used on a null stringBuilder
In this case  Finally sets your sb variable to null.
So don't use Finally

Comment: I know this, that is the issue. assigning NULL wont make it Garbage collected during GC cycle? Please advise.